# Setting debug to true in yaml instead of @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am NOT using Spring Boot, but I want to be able to turn on/off debugging with YAML such as:

```
debug: true
```

Instead of:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and [`WebSecurity#debug`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#debug-boolean-).

```java
@Value("${isDebugEnable}")
private Boolean isDebugEnable;

public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .debug(isDebugEnable)
        . //...
}
```